# jquery facebook share not working mobile but works on desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fully working facebook share pop up that work perfectly on desktop but just displays a facebook input field when viewed on a mobile device such as safari for the iphone?

DEMO FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/EYxTJ/345/

```
$('div').click(function(){   
    fb_click()
});

function fb_click() {
        var fb_title     = encodeURIComponent('my title goes here!');
        var fb_descr     = encodeURIComponent('my description goes here');
        var fb_url       = encodeURIComponent('www.example.com');
        var fb_image     = encodeURIComponent('http://www.highyieldbond.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/silver-apple-logo-apple-picture1.jpg');

        window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=' + fb_title + '&p[summary]=' + fb_descr + '&p[url]=' + fb_url + '&p[images][0]=' + fb_image, 'width=450','height=450');
    }
```

How it appears on a mobile device

[fb share mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4Nxk.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Some mobile devices do not handle click events. You have to use:

```
$('div').bind("click touchstart", function(){   
    fb_click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the event itself is being triggered ok. It just is not being dealt with correctly by the facebook API. For completeness i tried it and it didn't work DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/EYxTJ/346/

Comment: I tried the above method on safari and chrome for iPhone and it did not solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem. You have two options (to my knowledge).

1) Use the `php` facebook SDK which is incredibly easy to use.

2) Use inline javascript as this seems to bypass the common problem

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/5kNAw/1/

The sharer.php method does not allow parameters to be parsed to the mobile version of facebook. A work around is to load the desktop version for your share pop. You can do this using you JS function as above but with a small modification to the URL. As you will see in the example below i have added `m2w&` just after `sharer.php`. `m2w` means "mobile to web".

`window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?m2w&s=100&p[title]=' + fb_title + '&p[summary]=' + fb_descr + '&p[url]=' + fb_url + '&p[images][0]=' + fb_image, 'width=450','height=450');`

Comment: Sorry, i've had to unaccept as this only works if you specify a URL only. Once i add summary and title it has the same problem as before. Why is this issue so difficult to fix!?  :(